# Continuation in part to overcome concerns of undue experimentation

Tags: continuation-in-part

If I want to add details to a patent submitted to the uspto in order to add detail to overcome fears of the need for undue experimentation, will a flow up with a continuation in part mitigate the risk of need for undue experimentation?

Comment: Could you clarify where the fears come from?

Comment: I have an electrical engineering patent.  In it I say to use an amplifier but I didn't provide any details as to what sort of amplifier to use.  The context of the invention strongly suggests the use of a "Class D amplifier" and I think it is fairly obvious to one "practiced in the art."  However, I would like to mitigate the risk that the patent isn't enabling and add that detail.  

One could analyze the nature of the risk; however, my preference is to simply avoid it by filling some sort of continuation.

Comment: @JordanMcBain does the description provide working examples with Class D amplifier

Comment: No it does not.  The broad claims never become so specific either.  But my intent is to mitigate the risk with a cup if appropriate even if something in the existinf patent were to save the possible deficit

Comment: Just my opinion: if the invention doesn't solely work with a specific, obscure, amplifier, it is enabled. The theoretical person skilled in the art isn't, well, dumb. The person skilled in the art doesn't do the thinking for you, unless you find a authoritative source saying it's common knowledge in the field, but if any common amplifier works, you're very probably fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - Whether a CIP or a straight continuation, you can add the new material BUT in both cases you effectively *loose the original priority date*.  A way to have your cake and eat it too would be to pursue both applications. In that case  would file the CIP after the allowance on the parent - **but before the grant date**. Examiners do not usually reject for lack of enablement.

With different claim wording you might be able to get both granted with a terminal disclaimer. I'm a patent agent, but not an attorney but an attorney might think you would then have one with better enablement and one with a better priority date. Issues of patent enforcement are outside my expertise.

Comment: Thank you.  I think the "missing" details would be blatantly obvious to one practiced in the art but my risk management strategy has to include what a Yahoo judge might do.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to a lawyer today and the answer was yes a CIP can resolve such issues.  Who knows how much that advice is worth.

Thinking about it a bit more myself, this sort of makes sense since continuations and CIP's are typically used to overcome issues when examiners reject claims.

Comment: Whether a CIP or a straight continuation, you can add the new material BUT in both cases you effectively loose the original priority date.

Comment: I found an interesting article that adds to the benefits/pitfalls of CIP's: https://www.napp.org/index.php?option=com_dailyplanetblog&view=entry&year=2018&month=08&day=20&id=5:title-never-file-a-continuation-in-part